# how different with sklearn.iterativeimputer and pandas.interpolate(method='linear')?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, interpolation

how
`sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer(estimator='linear')`
and
`pandas.interpolate(method='linear')`?

I would really appreciate it if anyone who knows a little bit about this could mention it really briefly

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies `pandas.interpolate(method='linear')` assumes your rows are ordered, and fills in the NaNs in each column by taking the mean of the preceding and succeeding value.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame([[7, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, 5, 9],[np.nan,7,12],[5,9,14]])

      0    1   2
0   7.0  2.0   3
1   4.0  NaN   6
2  10.0  5.0   9
3   NaN  7.0  12
4   5.0  9.0  14
```

If we do X.interpolate(method="linear"), we can see that in the first column, the NaN is filled by (10+5) / 2 = 7.5 and the NaN in the 2nd column is filled by (2 + 5)/ 2 = 3.5.

```
X.interpolate(method="linear")

      0    1   2
0   7.0  2.0   3
1   4.0  3.5   6
2  10.0  5.0   9
3   7.5  7.0  12
4   5.0  9.0  14
```

So you can see this imputation happens independent of other columns or variables.

For `sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer` it's a bit more complex. By default (setting initial_strategy = "mean"), it imputes the missing values by filling in the mean of column. On this imputed matrix, it fits a model using your column to impute as a dependent variable and other columns as independent. From this model, it predicts the missing value, based on your non missing entries in other columns. By default the model used is `BayesianRidge()`.

As an example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

imputed_X = SimpleImputer(strategy="mean").fit_transform(X)
imputed_X

array([[ 7.  ,  2.  ,  3.  ],
       [ 4.  ,  5.75,  6.  ],
       [10.  ,  5.  ,  9.  ],
       [ 6.5 ,  7.  , 12.  ],
       [ 5.  ,  9.  , 14.  ]])
```

You can see the missing values are replaced by mean of columns. Now the model fitting, using the first column as an example:

```
mdl = BayesianRidge().fit(imputed_X[:,1:],imputed_X[:,0])
mdl.predict(X.loc[[3],1:])
array([6.49820435])
```

You get the same value 6.49820435 in the first column, 3rd row, where the missing value was previously :

```
IterativeImputer(random_state=0).fit_transform(X)

array([[ 7.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 4.        ,  4.30503804,  6.        ],
       [10.        ,  5.        ,  9.        ],
       [ 6.4987435 ,  7.        , 12.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  9.        , 14.        ]])
```